# Howto get MSXMLDOMDocument.selectSingleNode working with namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, asp-classic

I have classic ASP environment with MSXMLDOMDocument. The loaded xml is a xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-datatypes"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml xsl fn xs xdt">

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to get the version of the stylesheet, in this example is this the value "2.0".
I wanted to use XPath for this purpouse, but my problem is that i don't know how to add the namespace of xsl to xpath engine in classic asp.

Question: How to get version attribute of the xsl:stylesheet using MSXMLDOMDocument in classic asp?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution. Detailed explanation is also provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIR, there is a way to register a namespace, so that you can use the registered prefix in XPath expressions.

**However, in your case this isn't necesary**.

Just use:

```
/*/@version
```

Here we use the fact that `xsl:stylesheet` is the top element of the XML document (and that any well-formed XML document must have exactly one top element) -- so we can specify this top element as above -- without specifying its name at all.

We don't need to specify any namespace for the `version` attribute because in XPath any unprefixed attribute name is in "no namespace", even when there is a default namespace defined for the XML document.